# Is it possible for a Spring Data Page to contain a stream or iterator for the data?

Tags: memory, spring-data-jpa

I am just writing up the API and implementation spec and I was thinking of using Spring Data JPA to handle the paging of the results.  The Page class already contains information I need which is the total number of records for the whole collection but I want to avoid loading the all the records in the page into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all data in smaller chunks.
First of all you need to have `count` of the whole data.

```java
long count = (your_count_query)
```

Then make a total page according to the count.
`bulkSize` is the value you want each page to contain. f.e 10,000

```java
int totalPage = (int) Math.ceil(count * 1.0 / bulkSize);
```

And finally get result through the loop.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < totalPage; i++) {
Pageable currentPageable = PageRequest.of(i, bulkSize, Sort.by("some_property"));
Page<Object> page= repository.findPage(currentPageable);
}
```